# Mysql database and php

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Tables:

```
UserInfo
--------
UserID
Status (if user is active in a specific group)
GroupCode

UploadInfo
--------
Title
Description
Filename
UserID
GroupCode
```

I want to have a search box that will search some data from table
UploadInfo that will depend on the User's GroupCode and its Status is
active

My function in PHP (im using meekrodb)

```
function search($searchVal, $whoIsLogin){
  $searchResult =DB::query("SELECT * FROM UserInfo as tbl1 INNER JOIN UploadInfo as tbl2 on(tbl1.UserID=tbl2.UserID) where (tbl1.UserID=%s and tbl1.Status='active'", $whoIsLogin);
}
```

This function only shows all files from the users group where it is active. However this function has no search function.

Any kind of method or function?

Comment: what is the value of `$searchVal`? where you used this variable inside your function?

Comment: Hehe i dont know yet.. I just try displaying all files from uploadinfo

Comment: is this a build in function or you are creating this?

Comment: Im creating it 

Comment: Any kind of function will help thank you!!! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created only the basic.Update as per your requirement.Assuming only 'and' clause. Add condition for 'or'.

Here is the example of calling:

```
$arrSearch = array("Filename" => 'abc.txt');
search($arrSearch,'<whoisloginval>','like');


function search($searchVal, $whoIsLogin,$conditionType=''){
    $like = 'no';
    switch($conditionType)
    {
       case "equal": $clause = "=";
       break;
       case "notequal": $clause = "!=";
       break;
       case "like": $clause = "%"; $like = 'yes';
       break;
     }
    if(is_array($searchVal))
    {
       foreach($searchVal as $k=>$v)
       {

          $cond .= " and". $k .(($like == 'yes') ? ' like \' ' : '') . $clause. (($like == 'yes') ? $clause .'\'' : '') . "$v";
       }
     }
   $searchResult =DB::query("SELECT * FROM UserInfo as tbl1 INNER JOIN UploadInfo as tbl2 on(tbl1.UserID=tbl2.UserID) where (tbl1.UserID=%s and tbl1.Status='active' $cond ", $whoIsLogin);
  return $searchResult;
}
```

Comment: you need to modify it, as it does not work for multitype condition like where column='val' and column1='val1'  or column1='val1'.